# iOS - Timing User Reading Time While Able To Be Paused

Tags: ios, objective-c

Part of my app let's my user read an article while the app times him how long it took to read that article. When the user presses the done button at the bottom, a `UIAlertView` pops up saying "Article finished in whatever minutes and whatever seconds. Your speed was x words per minute. Word count: x". This is my code that does this:

```
@implementation ArticleWebViewController

NSDate *readingStartTime;
NSDate *readingEndTime;
NSTimeInterval readingTime;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //start reading timer for the user
    readingStartTime = [NSDate date];
}

- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    readingEndTime = [NSDate date];
    readingTime = [readingEndTime timeIntervalSinceDate:readingStartTime];
    NSNumber *wordCount = self.article.wordCount;
    NSNumber *totalSeconds = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:roundf(readingTime)];
    NSNumber *secondsInMinute = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:60];
    NSNumber *wordsPerSecondSpeed = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalSeconds.floatValue/secondsInMinute.floatValue];
    NSNumber *wordsPerMinuteSpeed = [NSNumber numberWithInt:roundf(wordCount.floatValue/wordsPerSecondSpeed.floatValue)];
    NSString *message;
    if (readingTime < 60)
    {
        message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %@ seconds.", totalSeconds];
    }
    else if (readingTime < 3600)
    {
        NSNumber *totalMinutes = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalSeconds.floatValue/secondsInMinute.floatValue];
        NSNumber *leftOverSeconds = [NSNumber numberWithInt:totalSeconds.intValue % secondsInMinute.intValue];
        if (leftOverSeconds > 0)
        {
            if (totalMinutes.intValue == 1) {
                if (leftOverSeconds.intValue == 1)
                {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i minute %i second.", totalMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
                else
                {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i minute %i seconds.", totalMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (leftOverSeconds.intValue == 1) {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i minutes %i second.", totalMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
                else
                {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i minutes %i seconds.", totalMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (totalMinutes.intValue == 1) {
                message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i minute.", totalMinutes.intValue];
            }
            else
            {
                message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i minutes.", totalMinutes.intValue];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSNumber *secondsInHour = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3600];
        NSNumber *totalHours = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalSeconds.floatValue/3600];
        NSNumber *leftOverMinutes = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(totalSeconds.intValue%secondsInHour.intValue)/secondsInMinute.floatValue];
        NSNumber *leftOverSeconds = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalSeconds.intValue%secondsInHour.intValue];
        if (totalHours.intValue == 1) {
            if (leftOverMinutes.intValue == 1)
            {
                if (leftOverSeconds.intValue == 1) {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i hour %i minute %i second.", totalHours.intValue, leftOverMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
                else {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i hour %i minute %i seconds.", totalHours.intValue, leftOverMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
            }
            else {
                if (leftOverSeconds.intValue == 1) {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i hour %i minutes %i second.", totalHours.intValue, leftOverMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
                else {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i hour %i minutes %i seconds.", totalHours.intValue, leftOverMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (leftOverMinutes.intValue == 1)
            {
                if (leftOverSeconds.intValue == 1) {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i hours %i minute %i second.", totalHours.intValue, leftOverMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
                else {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i hours %i minute %i seconds.", totalHours.intValue, leftOverMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
            }
            else {
                if (leftOverSeconds.intValue == 1) {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i hours %i minutes %i second.", totalHours.intValue, leftOverMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
                else {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article finished in %i hours %i minutes %i seconds.", totalHours.intValue, leftOverMinutes.intValue, leftOverSeconds.intValue];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    message = [message stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Your speed was %i words per minute. Word count: %i",wordsPerMinuteSpeed.intValue, wordCount.intValue]];
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done Reading!" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
}
```

I now need to add a pause button just in case a user wants to pause the timer in case he get's a phone call, text message, etc. So how would I be able to implement a pause functionality? How would I store the paused timestamps, considering that a user can press pause and resume multiple time? I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: why do you need a NSTimer for this, why can't you record the readingTime for each pause and add them, also reset readingStartTime when they press read again

Comment: Oh shoot, my mistake, I'm NOT using an NSTimer for this. I was using it somewhere else in my app. I gotta take that out.

Comment: So in terms of making an `NSArray` of `NSDate`s of every time the user paused?

Comment: you cant do that with nsdate. you need to have nstimer .

Comment: You can reduce the code dramatically by using `NSDateComponentsFormatter` to create the time left string.

Comment: do you need to also store the time they were paused for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    readingStartTime = [NSDate date];
    totalReadingTime = 0;
    //When the user receives phone call
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(pauseReadingTime)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
    //when the app resumes
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(resumeReadingTime)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)pauseReadingTime {
    readingEndTime = [NSDate date];
    totalReadingTime += [readingEndTime timeIntervalSinceDate:readingStartTime];
}

- (void)resumeReadingTime {
    readingStartTime = [NSDate date];
}
```

As you can see from the code snippet I have added two helper methods, pauseReadingTime and resumeReadingTime. So when the user presses done, pause or resume call the appropriate methods and also added NSNotification observers that registers when he receives calls etc, if you need additional notifications like did enter background, you can register that here as well.

Comment: This worked nicely, thanks! I didn't need to use the notification because there's a pause button that'll tell it when. :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any timers, just 4 time variables a start_resume method and a pause method.

0) Reset

```
CFTimeInterval startTime=0.0;
CFTimeInterval pauseTime=0.0;
CFTimeInterval pausedDuration=0.0;
CFTimeInterval readingTime=0.0;
```

1) Users starts/resumes reading:

```
// If we were paused, record how long for onto our running total
if (pauseTime > 0.0){
  // Reader was paused. Keep track of for how long.
  pausedDuration += (CACurrentMediaTime() - pauseTime);

  // Reset pauseTime as nolonger paused.
  pauseTime = 0.0;
}
else{
  // First time. Record start time
  startTime=CACurrentMediaTime();
}
```

2) User pauses

```
pauseTime=CACurrentMediaTime();
```

3) User finished

```
readingTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime - pausedDuration
```

Thats all you should need. readingTime is a double precision in seconds. Convert to however you want to display it.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the time when you want your `NSTimer` to pause then `invalidate` the  your timer, when you resume your timer assign the captured time to your timer using `setFireDate`.Capture the current time only using `[NSDate date]`

For more detail check this

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using an NSTimer with this. That was my mistake even mentioning it. Very sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save Multiple things:

The start time for the current interval.
A flag that indicates that the user is actively reading.
A total time value (NSTimeInterval would be perfect for this.)

When the user starts reading, save `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` to an instance variable (`readingStartTime`) and set your `isTiming` flag to YES.

When the user stops reading, calculate the amount of time passed since `readingStartTime` and add that to total time.

Lather, rinse, repeat.

Once the user is done, display the total time.